# How to set height to a React Component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've tried almost everything to set height to a react components but it doesn't seem to be working,but when I set width in the same manner it works! I'm using `<card>` from Material-ui.

Here is an example:

```
const Sty1={
height:'100%'
}

const Threads = React.createClass({
render: function() {
return (
  <Card style={Sty1}>
   *other stuff*
   </Card>
     );
   }
});
```

Comment: Is this a typo? You declare `Sty1` but use `st1`.

Comment: ive made a mistake it should be Sty1. ill update the question

Comment: And shouldn't it be `const Sty1 = { height: 100%; }` (so without the quotes)

Comment: Nop ive already tried that and its giving a syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying a relative height which doesn't work on the Card component. Use fixed dimension, or use a Paper.

Comment: Used the Paper and the styling worked like a charm! thank you!

Comment: Glad to know it worked. Please accept the answer to help track it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

See below:

```
style={ { height: 100 } } {your parameter to display}</td>
```

Above is for the column of the table.
It keeps the width default, do not change or specify.